# Websphere Portal Server Virtual Portal IBM Portal API

Tags: java, api, websphere-portal

I'm using the IBM Portal API for developing some pages in the Websphere Portal Server, but I want to work in the context of a virtual portal that is nested in my principal portal. I already read the documentation from IBM, but I don't understand how it work, so I decide to ask you guys. Does anyone of you did that already?
This is how I'm trying to get a ContentNode from my virtual portal:

```
private void createPortalContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException, ModelException{
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();

        portletModelHome = (PortletModelHome) ctx.lookup(PortletModelHome.JNDI_NAME);
        if(portletModelHome == null){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            portletModelHome = (PortletModelHome) ctx.lookup(PortletModelHome.JNDI_NAME);
        }

        contentModelHome = (ContentModelHome) ctx.lookup(ContentModelHome.JNDI_NAME);
        if(contentModelHome == null){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            contentModelHome = (ContentModelHome) ctx.lookup(ContentModelHome.JNDI_NAME);
        }

        contentModelControllerHome = (ContentModelControllerHome) ctx.lookup(ContentModelControllerHome.JNDI_NAME);
        if(contentModelControllerHome == null){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            contentModelControllerHome = (ContentModelControllerHome) ctx.lookup(ContentModelControllerHome.JNDI_NAME);
        }

        contentMappingInfoHome = (ContentMappingInfoHome) ctx.lookup(ContentMappingInfoHome.JNDI_NAME);
        if(contentMappingInfoHome == null){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            contentMappingInfoHome = (ContentMappingInfoHome) ctx.lookup(ContentMappingInfoHome.JNDI_NAME);
        }

        virtualPortalList = (VirtualPortalListHome) ctx.lookup(VirtualPortalListHome.VIRTUAL_PORTAL_LIST_JNDI_NAME);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ContentModelController contentModelController = getController(request, response);
    //LOGGER.info("### CONTENT MODEL CONTROLLER: " + contentModelController.getLocator() + " " + contentModelController.getRoot().toString());
    ContentNode contentNode = (ContentNode) contentModelController.getLocator().findByUniqueName("ro.ram.comunicate");
    //LOGGER.info("### CONTENT NODE: " + contentNode);
   // LOGGER.info("#### VIRTUAL PORTAL LIST: " + virtualPortalList);

    //VirtualPortal virtualPortal = virtualPortalList.getVirtualPortalListProvider().getVirtualPortalList().getLocator().findByUniqueName("");
   // LOGGER.info("### VIRTUAL PORTAL: " + virtualPortal.getTitle(Locale.ENGLISH));
    //Iterator<VirtualPortal> it=virtualPortalList.getVirtualPortalListProvider().getVirtualPortalList().iterator();
   // while(it.hasNext()){
   //     LOGGER.info("### VIRTUAL PORTAL LIST ITERATOR: " + it.next().getDescription(Locale.ENGLISH) + " " + " " + it.next().getTitle(Locale.ENGLISH));
  //      it.next();
    //}
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: What specific Portal API are you using?

Comment: I'm using the portal API that containts packages named like com.ibm.portal.*. The jars are wp.base.jar, wp.model.api.jar, etc.

Comment: the model api is pretty large, but if you are running the code from within the scope of a portlet it should already be scoped, like if you are using the model api to go over the content model it is already scoped to the current VP.  Now if you are trying to run it in a servlet that is outside the scope of the VP, like trying to create links or or something like that, you have to use objectids and the like to look for pages and what not.

And only parts of the model are VP scoped, like the portlet model is across vps.  we need some more details on what you want to do

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to create some portal-pages in a virtual portal, but i'm running the application into a servlet context, on Websphere Application Server. Mainly, I cannot reach the virtual portal context, because I'm trying to get a portal page template using the objectId of that page and I'm getting NullPointer. I put some code in the post for more detailes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who wants to do something like that, the solution (this was for me) might be:

1. Using IBM WCM API create a class that implements VirtualPortalScopedAction. In this class you must override the run method. The implementation of this interface makes it necessary.
2. In the run method you do all the math. Here you must instantiate the objects (ContentModelController, ContentModelHome, ContentModelControllerHome) that are exposed by IBM Portal API and SPI. All of these are necessary for making operations in IBM Websphere Portal.
3. In the class that implements VirtualPortalScopedAction you must pass the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, because instantiating all of that objects uses the request and the response. For that it's obvious that you declare two attributes in that class and use setter to set the instances on the request and response.

thx all of you :) I hope this will help you!

Comment: This saved my day. There are lots of forum entries stating it won't work at all, however this solution works perfectly

Comment: I know, when I faced this problem for the first time, I've lost about 1 week until this idea saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

So looking for unique names is a bad idea, you must look for the objectid of the page when working outside the scope of portal.  This comment from the infocenter
" The concept of virtual portals scopes some models to the virtual portal in which a user operates. At the moment, this scoping concept applies to the content model, the navigation model, and the navigation selection model. These models scope their resources to the virtual portal in which a user operates." 
 I think you would be best off, moving this code into the resource request of a portlet and then doing the update through that so it is scoped.  If you want to continue down this path, make it so the code does not look for uniquename but instead for the actual object id after using the Identification package to convert a string representation of an objectid into an actual object, then use the locator on that

Comment: I think I don't understand you, but once again, my problem is that I can run the application/the servlet in the context of the Virtual Portal. I cannot see the object that are placed in the Virtual Portal, but just the objects from the main portal. To be more precise, I already used the IBM WCM API for creating just content items in WCM for Virtual Portal, but there I've used the context of that portal by implementing VirtualPortalScopedAction and overriding run method. Now, IBM API and IBM SPI don't provides me something like that. Thx!